Error: LayoutBuilder does not support returning intrinsic dimensions

Error: LayoutBuilder does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.

void showDialogWithLayoutBuilder(){
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (context){
      return AlertDialog(
        content: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints){
            return Text("Very loooooong text");
          },
        ),
      );
    });
  }

How to make this work ? I don't want to wrap it by setting a hardcoded value of height and width.  This is a minimal reproducible code of the actual problem. In the real use case, LayoutBuilder is a package called AutoSizeText.

So, what's the purpose of using LayoutBuilder except using its parent constraints to impose on its child, you should wrap that text with a box widget with min^height constraints of layout builder.

I don't understand why AlertDialog uses IntrinsicWidth in the first place. I checked the code, it just seems to be Dialog does not use it. I am curious what would happen if we remove that IntrinsicWidth wrapper

You need to wrap the LayoutBuilder with a RenderBox that ignores the intrinsic functions, just like LayoutBuilder, but without errors and possibly without layout defects.
AlertDialog uses InstrinsicWidth to make the dialog look like it does, in the example you can see two SizedBox with different sizes but both widgets end up having the same width of 280, this value comes from a minWidth constraint in Dialog; in this layout, the column will chose the biggest minWidth from it's children as the width for all of them.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

void main() {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    debugCheckIntrinsicSizes = true;
  }

  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Home()));
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  String get o => List.generate(1000, (i) => 'o').join();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
            scrollable: true,
            title: const SizedBox(
              width: 0.0,
              child: Text('Short title'),
            ),
            content: SizedByChild(
              child: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (_, __) => SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Text('Very l${o}ng text'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SizedByChild extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const SizedByChild({super.key, super.child});

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) => RenderWithChildSize();
}

class RenderWithChildSize extends RenderBox with RenderObjectWithChildMixin<RenderBox> {
  @override
  void performLayout() {
    child?.layout(constraints, parentUsesSize: true);
    size = child?.size ?? constraints.smallest;
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    if (child != null) {
      context.paintChild(child as RenderBox, offset);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(BoxHitTestResult result, {required Offset position}) {
    return child?.hitTest(result, position: position) ?? false;
  }

  @override
  double? computeDistanceToActualBaseline(TextBaseline baseline) {
    return child?.getDistanceToActualBaseline(baseline);
  }
}


Could you explain what are the limitations/compromise of this solution? Especially this part " but without errors and possibly without layout defects."

Because the solution just circumvents the checks. I don't know how LayoutBuilder would do a bad layout but I asume that there is at least one edge case. I did try using an animated container and I had no issues so this might just be a design choice by the devs to encourage the use of better/faster layouts, just like with setState (see design discussion).
